# Changing Month of table name and dates in proc with loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pretty new to sql and I'm going through our Data Warehouse, which stores old data to add it all to one new table. There are many tables in DW one for each month; however, it stores multiple months data in the table, so I would have to add dates in as well. Is there a way to use a loop and automatically update the DW table name from [ACCOUNTHISTORYFEB2019] To March2019 (and so-on) and change the dates to the first day and last day of the following month? Thank you.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_BI_UpdatelyticsAHTable] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [xpnightly].[dbo].[20201124_lyticsAH3Year] ([XPTIMESTAMP]
      ,[ACCOUNT_HISTORY_ID],[ACTIVITY_ID],[MEMBER_NBR],[ACCT_NBR]
      ,[ACCT_SEQ_NBR],[BRANCH_NBR],[FOCUS_TELLER_ID],[ENTRY_DATE],[TRAN_AMT]
      ,[BEFORE_BAL],[PRINCIPAL_AMT]


      FROM [Data Warehouse].[dbo].[ACCOUNTHISTORYFEB2019] 
WHERE ([ENTRY_DATE] >= '02/01/2019' AND[ENTRY_DATE] <= '02/28/2019')
```

Comment: *"There are many tables in DW one for each month"* This is a design flaw unto itself. A table's name should not infer information that should be stored as a column. Normalising your design is the real key here. At the moment, the design requires dynamic SQL to use, which is never a good design choice. *Also, the query you have above appears to be incomplete.*

Comment: Thank you for the information! Unfortunately, I have nothing to with the design of tables as I work in analytics not a DBA. That said, it's good information to know and I will certainly remember it in the future! Thank you! Regarding the proc, which part looks incomplete? I'm only pulling in all data from one table and storing it in another. I honestly probably didn't need to do it as a proc.  I am interested in your thoughts on how to improve what I have though. I'm always happy to learn.

Comment: @Larnu, I've seen this design work really well with big tables which contain precalcualted raw data, I'm talking 10k inserts a second raw data, you only read then when you need to do a recalculation or the BI devs want to build a new datawarehouse, you can easily backup and archive months without needing to run expensive deletes, even move them to slow disks. Building indexes gets simplifiedbecuase you only need to reindex the latest table, the old tables indexes can be built with 0 padding one last time when moved. You can can also get this done with partitioning but you drive up complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use dynamic SQL for this, here is a quick demonstration of going through tables to get their row counts, you could adapt this to rename tables, generate aggregations and insert into fact tables etc.

```sql
/* This table will accumulate the results from our loop */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
CREATE TABLE #TestData
(
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    TableName VARCHAR(128),
    RowCounts BIGINT
)

/* This table will consist of the tables names I'd like to loop, for example tables starting with the letter t */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableNames
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.name) AS Id,
       T.name AS TableName
       INTO #TableNames
FROM sys.tables T
WHERE T.name LIKE 't%'

DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @total INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TableNames)
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

/* This is a basic while loop, you can achieve this with a cursor 
but while reads easier for someone with dev background */
WHILE(@i <= @total)
BEGIN

SELECT @tableName = T.TableName FROM #TableNames T WHERE T.Id = @i

SET @SQL = '
INSERT INTO #TestData
SELECT '''+@tableName+''',COUNT(*) FROM '+@tableName
PRINT(@sql)
EXEC (@sql)

SET @i += 1

END

SELECT * 
FROM #TestData TD
```